How to communicate between js and flutter webview?
I'm integrating webview in my flutter app.
Here is the relevant code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class _WebViewStackState extends State<WebViewStack> {
  var loaded = false;
  late WebViewController _webViewController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _webViewController = WebViewController()
      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(widget.url))
      ..setNavigationDelegate(
        NavigationDelegate(
          onPageStarted: (url) {},
          onProgress: (progress) {},
          onPageFinished: (url) {
            setState(() {
              loaded = true;
            });
          },
          onNavigationRequest: (navigation) {
            final host = Uri.parse(navigation.url).host;
            print(host);
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          },
        ),
      )
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..addJavaScriptChannel(
        'callNativeMethod',
        onMessageReceived: (message) {
          print(message.message);
        },
      )
      ..addJavaScriptChannel('callAnalysisEvents',
          onMessageReceived: (message) {
        print(message.message);
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(widget.url);

    return
        SafeArea(
            child: WebViewWidget(
      controller: _webViewController,
    ));
  }
}

This is the logic from the flutter side.and here is the code from the js side:
iOS:
messageHandlers.callNativeMethod.postMessage

Android:
window.external. CallNativeMethod(JSON.stringify({type,data}))

I can receive messages from the js side in iOS, but cannot in Android.
Already set this in AndroidManifest.xml:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

I also tried InAppWebView, but I didn't receive any message both in iOS and Android.
It's not possible to modify from the js side because it's from our customer; hope it working fine in both iOS and Android. have I missed something?
Any ideas?

For reference, this is how I call functions from js: window.flutter_inappwebview.callHandler('Flutter', {'functionName': functionName, 'parametersObj': parametersObj}); (using inappwebview), but if you can't change the js code that calls the flutter code, that's gonna be a problem :/
